# Menu bar items not displaying in RTL and Change title color

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

in menu.xml , I am having two items . It s displaying correctly in LTR mode.. But in RTL , it is not displaying correctly . One item is missing. I have attached the screenshot and code. And I need to change the color of the title name.
[image: LTR]
[image: RTL]

And I have added supportRTL="true" in manifest file

menu.xml

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/notification"
    android:title="Notification"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/badge_counter"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
  </menu>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    // Create a condition (hide it if the count == 0)
    if (mNotificationCounter > -1) {
        BadgeCounter.update(this,
                menu.findItem(R.id.notification),
                R.drawable.noti,
                BadgeCounter.BadgeColor.BLUE,
                mNotificationCounter);
    } else {
        BadgeCounter.hide(menu.findItem(R.id.notification));
    }

    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    this.menuItem = item;
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.notification) {
        // If you want to update
       // mNotificationCounter--;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Please see that notification icon alone missing.

Comment: rtl is working well as per image source. what do you want.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari notification white icon is missing in RTL mode

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanian - Have u found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define menu tag in..

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"

   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layoutDirection="rtl"
>
```